# How to Convert HexString To Little Endian Format in java?

Tags: android, hex, endianness

I want to pass bytearray in little endian format for bluetooth command.
I have converted integer duration to hexstring but i want this string in little endian format.

**Example :**

String command=Integer.toHexString(500);

Result is : 1F4

I want little endian format which is F401

Comment: see `java.nio.ByteBuffer`, `java.nio.ShortBuffer`, `java.nio.IntBuffer` etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly get little-endian integer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560836/how-to-properly-get-little-endian-integer-in-java)